# how to use ip camera as webcam in pc

Tags: webcam, ip-camera

I want to use **ip camera as webcam** in my application.
is there an application to create virtual webcam and could add ip for work?

Comment: What language? What OS? What framework?

Comment: did you get any further with this problem ? I have the same issue right now for mac os virtual machines

Comment: @Dukeatcoding unfortunately no

Comment: what kind of application do you have a flash one ? as far as i figured out , without an own convertor driver from motion stream to flash it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not specified what camera you're looking at or what operating system or language you're programming in so this addresses the general case:

With most IP cameras it's normally far easier to just pull the frames off the IP camera directly within your application. Typically that would be with an HTTP GET request which can be done with something like libcurl. This is much simpler than most camera interfaces for directly connected cameras since all of the encoding and capture options, device opening/closing get handled for you and what you receive is a JPEG or similar.

If you really want to make a virtual camera device this is pretty easy on Linux, e.g. with something like [v4l2vd](http://v4l2vd.sourceforge.net/), you need to write a bit of glue to connect that to your desired source, but it's fairly simple and what you get at the end of it looks like any other V4L2 device.